# Create javascript function that works with intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

I want to take advantage of visual studio intellisense therefore I have read:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx

Anyways why I do not get intellisense with:

```
function Customer() {
    this.Id = 0;
    this.FirstName = "";
    this.LastName = "";
}

function Test() {
    /// <returns type="Customer"></returns>

    var c = new Object();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "Ajax/GetCustomer.aspx",
        success: function (foundCustomer) {
            // I know that found customer is of type Customer
            c = foundCustomer;
        }
    });

    return c;
}

var x = Test();
x. // No intellicense! why?
```

How can I tell visual studio know that the function is going to return an object of TYPE `Customer`? For example if I replace the function Test for: `function Test(){ return new Customer(); }` then intellicense will work.

---

### Edit

My Goal at the end is to have something like:

```
function Customer() {
    this.Id = 0;
    this.FirstName = "";
    this.LastName = "";
}

Object.prototype.CastToCustomer = function(){
    /// <returns type="Customer"></returns>
    return this;
}

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "Ajax/GetCustomer.aspx",
    success: function (foundCustomer) {

        foundCustomer = foundCustomer.CastToCustomer();
        foundCustomer.// Intellicense does not work :(
    }
});
```

I get a lot of json objects and I will like to cast them using this helper functions.

---

### Temporary solution:

**This is what I ended up doing:**

```
function Customer() {
    this.Id = 0;
    this.FirstName = "";
    this.LastName = "";
}

$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "Ajax/GetCustomer.aspx",
    success: function (foundCustomer) {
        // this will never be true on real browser. It is always true in visual studio (visual studio will now think that found customer is of type Customer ;)
        if (document.URL.length == 0) foundCustomer = new Customer();

        foundCustomer.// Intellisense works!!!!
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you expect Intellisense to say here, you haven't added anything to type `Customer` itself ?

Comment: Id, FirstName and LastName... Same intellicense as if I where to do: `var x = new Customer(); x.// Intellicense will work!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the return value to an `Object` so it's on that which the Intellisense is based. If you initialize it to an empty `Customer`, then the Intellisense will detect that it is returning a `Customer`

```
function Test() {

    var c = new Customer(); //only for Intellisense

    $.ajax({...});

    return c;
}

Test(). //Customer members now appear
```

---

You can also use `/// <param />` to specify the parameter type:

```
$.ajax({
    ...

        success: function (foundCustomer) {
           /// <param name='foundCustomer' type='Customer' />
           foundCustomer. //Customer members appear            
        }
});
```

---

Finally, your `document.URL.length` trick can also be used in the casting method:

```
Object.prototype.CastToCustomer = function() {

  var c = new Customer();
  if (document.URL.length) c = this;
  return c;

}
```

Comment: Yeah I love `if (document.URL.length) c = this;` I will just use it before to make the cast and avoid having to write things like: `/// <param name='foundCustomer' type='Customer' />`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your Customer function to accept arguments:

```
function Customer(opts) {
    var opts = opts || {};

    this.id = 0;
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';

    for (var i in opts) {
        if (opts.hasOwnProperty(i)) this[i] = opts[i];
    }
}
```

Then inside your `Test` function, change `c = foundCustomer` to `c = new Customer(foundCustomer)`. I'm guessing this might trigger the intellicense?